# Data flow in Polymer Topeka example

Tags: polymer

Help needed in understanding the Polymer Topeka example (https://github.com/polymer/topeka). Included in the topeka-app element, the topeka-category element has an attribute & binding {{category}} but I don't understand what feeds the value of the "category" variable. The data must be coming from categories.json, and I do see this topeka-datasource element in the index.html, but I can't seem to figure out how the data goes into the category object (instead of categories) to be used in the topeka-category element.

Index.html includes:

```
<topeka-datasource url="bower_components/topeka-elements/categories.json" user="{{user}}" categories="{{categories}}" connected="{{connected}}"></topeka-datasource>
```

topeka-app.html includes:

```
<polymer-element name="topeka-app" attributes="user categories" vertical layout>
 <template>
    <topeka-category id="category" name="category" user="{{user}}" category="{{category}}" allScores="{{allScores}}" wide="{{wide}}"></topeka-category>    // notice a binding called category appears here, although there is no attribute or property of this name in the Polymer script
 </template>
 <script>
   Polymer('topeka-app',{
        categorySelect: function() {
        if (this.category) {          // can't figure out where the code that pulls data from categories.json to put data into this object.
          var n = this.category.name;
          if (n === 'leaderboard') {
            this.showLeaderboard();
          } else if (n === 'profile') {
            this.showProfile();
          } else {
            this.showCategory();
          }
        }
      }
    )
 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Excerpt from Topeka-category.html

```
<polymer-element name="topeka-category" attributes="user category selected wide allScores" vertical layout> // This has a "category" attribute, but again I'm not sure where this is coming from.

<script>

Polymer('topeka-category', {

created: function() {
  this.scores = [];
  this.category = {quizzes: []};  // This is all 'this.category' gets when the element is created, but eventually some content of categories.json goes into this object.
.....
})
 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/Polymer/topeka-elements/tree/9e72ec24b6bea4a86c07e8c9580f8463769566a4

**Edit:** Changed link to a specific git commit in case Topeka is updated for future Polymer version.

topeka-datasource is marking the attributes it takes by the following javascript.

```
Polymer('topeka-datasource', {
  publish: {
    user: null,
    categories: null,
    url: ''
  },
```

This is basically just an imperitive way of saying what attributes the polymer-element has.

topeka-datasource has a sub-element of

```
<core-ajax auto handleAs="json" url="{{url}}" response="{{categories}}"></core-ajax>
```

core-ajax is a really useful element, it can load JSON and load it straight into a polymer expression when it recieves a response. In this example, it's auto loading it as soon as core-ajax is ready, and feeding it back to {{categories}} which is published by topeka-datasource.

in the index

```
<template is="auto-binding">
<topeka-datasource url="components/topeka-elements/categories.json" user="{{user}}" categories="{{categories}}" connected="{{connected}}"></topeka-datasource>
<topeka-app fit user="{{user}}" categories="{{categories}}" connected="{{connected}}" touch-action="auto"></topeka-app>
</template>
```

The code is wrapped in an auto-binding template, because topeka-datasource and topeka-app tags are *not* contained within a polymer-element, and databinding can only happen with either polymer-elements, or bound templates, auto-binding just allows this to happen without having to reference another template.

So core-ajax loads the json into {{categories}} which is published, so can be accessed by parent/children (polymer-element / bound templates) topeka-app then takes the {{categories}} polymer expression.

An observer is generated for both topeka-datasource and topeka-app to watch and notify the elements of any changes to the auto-binded templates catergories object.

So in topeka-categories, whenever a category is selected, 
https://github.com/Polymer/topeka-elements/blob/40e3c88a69f2095a29548cfb34b22d1b1022510e/topeka-categories.html#L118

```
selectedChanged: function() {
  // first one is leaderboard, last one is profile
  if (this.selected === 0) {
    this.category = {name: 'leaderboard'};
  } else if (this.selected === this.categories.length + 1) {
    this.category = {name: 'profile'};
  } else {
    this.category = this.categories[this.selected - 1];
  }
```

this.category is bound to the {{category}} expression.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a perfect sense.